# Why isnt this simple grep/sed script working

Tags: sed, grep

I have a variable with, among others, a line that looks like this

```
iBMC=277
```

I'm trying to match that like this:

```
BMC="$(echo "$allnow" | grep iBMC=[0-9] | sed 's/iBMC=//g')"
```

This makes BMC empty. Here's what it looks like in `bash -x`:

```
++ grep 'iBMC=[0-9] '
++ sed s/iBMC=//g
+ BMC=
```

I also have to match more things, like in this line:

```
Name="$(echo "$allnow" | grep stringName= | sed 's/stringName=//g')"
```

But it also turns out empty. Here is `$allnow`:

```
QQ1=0999999
QQ2=00aaaaa
RR=yes
GG=no
stringName=skolan8
sTitle=
iBMC=277
L3-cache="8 MB"
Minne="16 GB"
```

Comment: `grep 'iBM=[0-9] '` isn't the same as `grep iBMC=[0-9]`. What did you type? Also, in `awk`: `BMC="$(echo "$allnow" | awk -F = '/iBMC=[0-9]/{print $2}')"`

Comment: Also, in sed:  `BMC="$(echo "$allnow" | sed -n 's/^iBMC=//g;T;P')"`

Comment: @muru That's exactly what I typed though.

Comment: FYI, the code you posted *should* have worked, even though it could be improved by removing the duplicate regex per line (see my answer).  Since your code *didn't* work, I suspect that the problem is with the setting of the `$allnow` variable.  For instance, if you set `allnow` from the interactive shell and are trying to access it from a script, you would need to use `export` (or rethink your strategy).  What does `echo "$allnow"` in the script show?

Comment: @Wildcard the last few lines was the output of "echo "$allnow"".

Comment: Run from the script, though?  Or from the command line?  To put it another way: Where and how is the variable `allnow` *set*?  Edit: Actually, I just looked again; @muru is right.  If `bash -x` shows you are grepping for `'iBMC=[0-9] '`, then that's your problem—you have more than one digit and no space in that line.

Comment: Inside the script, just before where I define `$BMC`.  It looks like this `allnow="$(cat "$1" | sed '/Vars/!d' | sed 's/\&/\(newline here)
/g' | sed '/STOP=/d' | sed 's/.*\<.*iBMC/iBMC/g' | awk '!a[$0]++')"` the (newline here) is a literal newline, it didn't show one in the comments here so I added that.

Comment: I'm sorry I asked...but it's more or less what I expected.  Free advice: (1) UUOC (google it) (2) Just do it all in `awk` rather than making a huge pipeline iterating through the file 9+ times to set your variables.  Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943.  But, to make it work as written, find out why you have an extra space showing in the arg to `grep`; that's your immediate trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use a grep (maybe for performance issue on huge info, but i don't think this is the case with data stored in a variable)

```
BMC="$(echo "${allnow}" | sed -e '/iBMC=[0-9]/!d' -e 's/iBMC=//;q' )"
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @NeronLeVelu's answer, but I get suspicious when I see the same or nearly the same regex in two places in a `sed` script.  ;)

Sure enough, it can be simplified:

```
sed -n 's/iBMC=//;T;/^[0-9]/p'
```

Or, if using BSD `sed` where there is no `T`, you can use the sloppy workaround:

```
sed -n -e 's/iBMC=//;ta' -e 'b' -e ':a' -e '/^[0-9]/p'
```

On the other hand, we could just get simple about the whole thing:

```
sed -n 's/iBMC=\([0-9]\)/\1/p'
```

which is the exact same length as my first version, but portable to BSD `sed`.

So wrap this like so:

```
BMC="$(echo "$allnow" | sed -n 's/^iBMC=\([0-9]\)/\1/p')"
Name="$(echo "$allnow" | sed -n 's/^stringName=//p')"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "space" after `]` wasn't actually a space but `¬†`. It looked the same in BBEdit, but after opening it with HexFiend, it showed me that character. There is some shortcut in BBEdit that makes `¬†` instead of space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<<IN \
grep '^iBMC=[0-9]\|^stringName=' |\
sed 's/^[[:lower:]]*//'
$allnow
IN
```

You also might want to check your file for clean line-endings, but I don't know about that.